# Element disabled for editing ckeditor 4

Tags: javascript, php

I load ckeditor 4 on my page with this code:

```
    <textarea id="editor1">
        <?php
            echo $data['text'];
        ?>
    </textarea>

<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.8.0/full-all/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script>
    CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
        toolbar: [
            { name: 'document', items: [ 'Print' ] },
            { name: 'clipboard', items: [ 'Undo', 'Redo' ] },
            { name: 'styles', items: [ 'Format', 'Font', 'FontSize' ] },
            { name: 'basicstyles', items: [ 'Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike', 'RemoveFormat', 'CopyFormatting' ] },
            { name: 'colors', items: [ 'TextColor', 'BGColor' ] },
            { name: 'align', items: [ 'JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight', 'JustifyBlock' ] },
            { name: 'links', items: [ 'Link', 'Unlink' ] },
            { name: 'paragraph', items: [ 'NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Outdent', 'Indent', '-', 'Blockquote' ] },
            { name: 'insert', items: [ 'Image', 'Table' ] },
            { name: 'tools', items: [ 'Maximize' ] },
            { name: 'editing', items: [ 'Scayt' ] }
        ],
        customConfig: '',
        disallowedContent: 'img{width,height,float}',
        extraAllowedContent: 'img[width,height,align]',
        extraPlugins: 'tableresize,uploadimage,uploadfile',
        height: 800,
        contentsCss: [ 'https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.8.0/full-all/contents.css', 'mystyles.css' ],
        bodyClass: 'document-editor',
        format_tags: 'p;h1;h2;h3;pre',
        removeDialogTabs: 'image:advanced;link:advanced',
        stylesSet: [
            /* Inline Styles */
            { name: 'Marker', element: 'span', attributes: { 'class': 'marker' } },
            { name: 'Cited Work', element: 'cite' },
            { name: 'Inline Quotation', element: 'q' },
            /* Object Styles */
            {
                name: 'Special Container',
                element: 'div',
                styles: {
                    padding: '5px 10px',
                    background: '#eee',
                    border: '1px solid #ccc'
                }
            },
            {
                name: 'Compact table',
                element: 'table',
                attributes: {
                    cellpadding: '5',
                    cellspacing: '0',
                    border: '1',
                    bordercolor: '#ccc'
                },
                styles: {
                    'border-collapse': 'collapse'
                }
            },
            { name: 'Borderless Table', element: 'table', styles: { 'border-style': 'hidden', 'background-color': '#E6E6FA' } },
            { name: 'Square Bulleted List', element: 'ul', styles: { 'list-style-type': 'square' } }
        ]
    } );
</script>
```

In my variable `$data['text']` I have some texts that are enclosed in brackets, for example like this: `{Content_Date}`. I need all this data in brackets not to be editable, but rather that it is possible to click and drag them to other rows and positions within the ckeditor.